# SQL: select next available date for multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle DB.
My table has `ID` and `DATE` columns (and more).
I would like to select for every ID the next available record after a certain date. For only one `ID` the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE id = 1 AND date >= '01.01.2018'
```

(just ignoring the `to_date()` function)

How would that look like for multiple IDs? And I do want to `SELECT *`.

Thanks!

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  and the expected  result  .

Comment: your question is hard to understand.

Comment: Is select top(1) * from table   where Id = 1 and date > {x} order by date desc.   a start to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @LJ01 That won't generalize well for more than one ID.

Comment: @tim    upvoted you're answer because it does.... The single id might help someone else with different scenarios so won't remove comment

Comment: @LJ01 I agree that your suggestion would work well for a single `ID` +1.

Comment: `'01.01.2018'` should be `date '2018-01-01'`. No `to_date()` function required. [Some sample data would help clarify what you want.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve)

Comment: I put a down vote because reading the question and looking at the suggested answer below, the complicated answer can be as simple as select * from tbl where date >= date 01.01.2018. You should put sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT ID, date  -- and maybe other columns
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM my_table
    WHERE date >= date '2018-01-01'
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

The idea here is to assign a row number to each `ID` partition, starting with the *earliest* date which occurs after the cutoff you specify.  The first record from each partition would then be the immediate next date, assuming it exists.